# CiviBanking : No valid booking date detected. Not imported!

Tags: civibanking

I am using civicrm extension 
CiviBanking
https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/master/doc/civibanking-getting-started.md
I created a record in the table civicrm_bank_plugin_instance, with config data
in JSON format where my booking_date is configured as given below
While trying to use the CSV Importer plugin in CiviBanking https://www.example.com/civicrm/banking/import

```
{
  "namespaces": {
    "camt": "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"
  },
  "probe": "camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:GrpHdr/camt:MsgId",
  "rules": [
    {
      "comment": "statement name is MsgId/LglSeqNb",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:GrpHdr/camt:MsgId",
      "to": "tx_batch.reference",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "comment": "statement name is MsgId/LglSeqNb",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:LglSeqNb",
      "to": "tx_batch.reference",
      "type": "append:/"
    },
    {
      "comment": "statement sequence number",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:LglSeqNb",
      "to": "tx_batch.sequence",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "comment": "IBAN preset for payments",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:Acct/camt:Id/camt:IBAN",
      "to": "tx._IBAN",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "comment": "BIC preset for payments",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:Acct/camt:Svcr/camt:FinInstnId/camt:BIC",
      "to": "tx._BIC",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "comment": "starting time",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:FrToDt/camt:FrDtTm",
      "to": "tx_batch.starting_date",
      "type": "strtotime"
    },
    {
      "comment": "ending time",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:FrToDt/camt:ToDtTm",
      "to": "tx_batch.ending_date",
      "type": "strtotime"
    },
    {
      "comment": "statement currency",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:Bal[1]/camt:Amt/@Ccy",
      "to": "tx_batch.currency",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "comment": "statement starting balance. FIXME: include condition instead of position",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:Bal[2]/camt:Amt",
      "to": "tx_batch.starting_balance",
      "type": "amount"
    },
    {
      "comment": "statement starting balance. FIXME: include condition instead of position",
      "from": "xpath:camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:Bal[1]/camt:Amt",
      "to": "tx_batch.ending_balance",
      "type": "amount"
    }
  ],
  "payments": {
    "path": "camt:BkToCstmrStmt/camt:Stmt/camt:Ntry",
    "rules": [
      {
        "comment": "booking date",
        "from": "xpath:camt:BookgDt/camt:Dt",
        "to": "booking_date",
        "type": "strtotime"
      },
      {
        "comment": "value date",
        "from": "xpath:camt:ValDt/camt:Dt",
        "to": "value_date",
        "type": "strtotime"
      },
      {
        "comment": "Amount",
        "from": "xpath:camt:Amt",
        "to": "amount",
        "type": "amount"
      },
      {
        "comment": "Currency",
        "from": "xpath:camt:Amt/@Ccy",
        "to": "currency",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "party IBAN",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:RltdPties/camt:DbtrAcct/camt:Id/camt:IBAN",
        "to": "_party_IBAN",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "party BIC",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:RltdAgts/camt:DbtrAgt/camt:FinInstnId/camt:BIC",
        "to": "_party_BIC",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "transaction message",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:AddtlTxInf",
        "to": "purpose",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "party name",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:RltdPties/camt:Dbtr/camt:Nm",
        "to": "name",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "party address",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:RltdPties/camt:Dbtr/camt:PstlAdr/camt:StrtNm",
        "to": "street_address",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "party address",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:RltdPties/camt:Dbtr/camt:PstlAdr/camt:TwnNm",
        "to": "city",
        "type": "set"
      },
      {
        "comment": "party address",
        "from": "xpath:camt:NtryDtls/camt:TxDtls/camt:RltdPties/camt:Dbtr/camt:PstlAdr/camt:Ctry",
        "to": "country",
        "type": "set"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and my CSV has data as given below

```
"Datum","Naam / Omschrijving","Rekening","Tegenrekening","Code","Af Bij","Bedrag (EUR)","MutatieSoort","Mededelingen"
"20180212","STICHTING GYM-SUPPORT","NL21INGB111111111","NL76RAB11111111","OV","Bij","100,00","Overschrijving","Naam: STICHTING GYM-SUPPORT Omschrijving: Bestelling Lyme magazine IBAN: NL76RAB11111111"
```

I tried changing type for booking date from "type": "strtotime" to "type": "strtotime:Ymd" but it still gives error.
How can I fix it?
My civicrm version is 4.6.22

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration seems not to be correct. And to me it looks like you have set up a configuration for an XML (CAMT0.53) file and your example looks like a CVS file.

You can use one of the examples from the CSV directory as an example and the tweak it to your needs: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/tree/master/configuration_database/importer/csv

Below a configuration which works with the example csv file you provided in the question:

```
{
  "delimiter": ",",
  "encoding": "UTF8",
  "header": 1,
  "defaults": {},
  "rules": [
    {
      "from": "Datum",
      "to": "booking_date",
      "type": "strtotime:Ymd"
    },
    {
      "from": "Datum",
      "to": "value_date",
      "type": "strtotime:Ymd"
    },
    {
      "from": "Naam / Omschrijving",
      "to": "name",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "from": "Bedrag (EUR)",
      "to": "amount",
      "type": "amount"
    },
    {
      "from": "_constant:EUR",
      "to": "currency",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "from": "Mededelingen",
      "to": "purpose",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "from": "Tegenrekening",
      "to": "_party_ba_id",
      "type": "set"
    },
    {
      "from": "Rekening",
      "to": "_bank_id",
      "type": "set"
    }
  ]
}
```

**A few remarks**:

I dont know what would happen if a write-off is present in the file. Is that indicated by a negative amount? Or is the column Bij Af / set to Af.

The name in the *from* part of a rule is the name of the column in the csv file. However there is also a from which sets a constant value to EUR.

The name in *to* part is the name of the field in the CiviBanking transaction. You could define new fields here as you can use existing ones (like booking_date, value_date, amount and purpose). The new ones can be used in the configuration of the matchers. However I have not defined any new fields here.

Comment: Your configuration seems not to be correct. And to me it looks like you have set up a configuration for an XML (CAMT0.53) file and your example looks like a CVS file.

Did you mean CVS or CSV as mentioned above?

Comment: Also, I tried to import CSV files from the example, but every time I do that my booking_date value is shown as 01-01-1970 when I set type for booking_date as "type": "strtotime:Ymd" since my date is set as 20180212 even when I import is successful, any ideas on how can dateformat be fixed?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example of a configuration.

Comment: Bij is received. Af is payed.

Comment: How did you come to know about adding _constant:EUR in from,what was reference point while implementing it,I did see it in examples but nothing apart from it.let me know,thanks. Also thanks a lot, your solution worked very well @Jaap Jansma

Comment: I have done two implementations with CiviBanking and I have looked a few things up in the code.

Comment: Hi @Japp Jansma , I need an example of how to add Matcher Plugin, is this somewhat which you can help on?

Comment: I have answerred your question