# How to add a Matcher Plugin in CiviBanking as I get "No Matcher Plugin Found"?

Tags: civibanking

I was able to Import Bank Statement To Civicrm with the help of this
[CiviBanking : No valid booking date detected. Not imported!](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22748/civibanking-no-valid-booking-date-detected-not-imported)

Now my second task is to add Matcher Plugin.
In [Wiki Docs](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/master/doc/civibanking-getting-started.md),
I see a list of matchers

> **Default Options** - creates two default suggestions: manual
>   reconciliation and ignore
>
> **Batch Matcher** - matches to payment batches
>
> **Contribution Matcher** - matches to existing contributions  **Create**
>
> **Contribution Matcher** - creates suggestions to create now contribtuions
>
> **Ignore Matcher** - can be configured to automatically ignore certain
>   transactions
>
> **Membership Matcher Plugin** - records transactions as
>   membership dues
>
> **Recurring Contribution Matcher Plugin** - reccords transactions as > installments of recurring contribtuions
>
> **SEPA Matcher** - intgrates with the CiviSEPA extension

I see a configuration in json format here :
https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/blob/master/configuration_database/matcher/default/EnglishDefaults.json

```
{
    "generate": 1,
    "auto_exec": false,
    "manual_enabled": true,
    "manual_probability": "50%",
    "manual_show_always": true,
    "manual_title": "Manually processed",
    "manual_message": "Select this <strong>after</strong> you have manually processed this transaction.",
    "manual_contribution": "Please enter the resulting contribution ID here (if applicable):",
    "manual_default_source": "Offline",
    "manual_default_financial_type_id": 1,
    "ignore_enabled": true,
    "ignore_show_always": true,
    "ignore_probability": "0.1",
    "ignore_title": "Not CiviCRM related",
    "ignore_message": "Choose this option if you are positive that this transaction has nothing to do with CiviCRM.",
    "value_propagation": {
        "ba.name_id": "contribution.custom_14",
        "btx.financial_type_id": "contribution.financial_type_id",
        "btx.campaign_id": "contribution.campaign_id"
    },
    "lookup_contact_by_name" : {
        "soft_cap_probability": 0.8, 
        "soft_cap_min": 10, 
        "hard_cap_probability": 0.4
    }
}
```

Where do we need to add this configuration in database so that I can see the matcher plugin?

Answer (score 2):

A matcher is added just like an importer on the configuration screen. The configuration screen has different sections. The top one is the importer, then the **matchers**, then post processors and the last one are exporter plugins.

See below for a screenshot:

[image: How to add a matcher]

After you click on Add a matcher you are able to select a matcher type and a configuration for that matcher type.